# How to minimize a running program using a command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

Please note that I am familiar with the command line that is supposed to OPEN and run a program minimized, however that just doesn't work with some third-party programs. So I thought I could use a batch file with two command lines - one to open the program and the other to minimize it. I wonder if that would work.

Comment: It can't be done natively in CMD. You would need to either use a third-party program, such as nircmd or write a batch script or vbscript that does this. The batch script would in essence write the vbscript and then execute it.

Comment: I see, and do you happen to know the nircmd command line to do that? I couldn't find it anywhere on their website.

Comment: http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendmouse.html

Comment: So the sendmouse by nirsoft didn't work for me but I found a similar solution using AutoHotkey (MouseClick, left, x, y) and that does the trick. It's all quite complicated but my problem is solved now. Thank you LPChip for you idea.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [**NirCmd**](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). From [NirCmd's help file,](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#win) the command to minimize windows or running programs is:

```
nircmd win min [find] [window to find] [Additional Parameters]
```

For example, to minimize all open notepad.exe windows:

```
nircmd win min process "notepad.exe"
```

See [NirCmd's help file](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd2.html#win) for more info on how to specify which windows or running programs you want minimized.

Answer (score -1):

Here is minimalistic implementation of tiny utility program in pure Windows API (except string manipulation, which uses my custom text type):

```cpp
// CONSOLE nDBG
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <utf>

#pragma comment( lib, "user32")

txt to_min = 1024;

#pragma warning( suppress : 4100 )
BOOL __declspec(nothrow) CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lp)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    
    HANDLE hproc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    
    if(hproc == NULL)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    
    char buff[500];
    if(GetProcessImageFileNameA(hproc, buff, 500))
    {
        txt n = buff;
        txtd(n, 0, ("\\" << n) + 1);
        if(n == to_min && IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
        {
            SendMessageTimeoutA(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 25, NULL);
            return FALSE;
        }
    } 
    
    return TRUE;
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    to_min = wt2u8(argv[1]);
    
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it and then you can just call it with the argument of the image name of the process which windows you want to minimise.

Comment: This seems complicated, requiring a user (who may not have programming knowledge) to *compile* source code. OP is just looking to run a program using a batch file or command line. Do you have links to a binary?